# Whats the difference between a Controller and a Middleware

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am writing and API in express.js. the original API I wrote only utilized routes and raw SQL queries. I have since rewritten the API for the most part NOW using an ORM to react models and migrations.

My question what is the difference and use cases for middleware and controllers. currently only using middleware because most sources online online only explain what a middleware is.

I don't understand the use case of a controller. and I don't want to omit it from my API if its used in proper programming conventions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should see middleware as a step in your API and controllers as the entity that will actually respond to the requests.

Bellow is an example where `authenticationMiddleware` is a middleware because it is a step during the processing but should not return the response. It can though, in case of error.

Then `getItems` actually handle the logic specific to this calls.

As a rule of thumb, middleware are often reused more than once and often they do not response. On contrary, controller respond and are most of the time specific to one endpoint.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

function authenticationMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  // Check that the user is authenticated using req.headers.Authorization
  // for example

  if (authenticated) {
    // The user is authenticated, we can go to the next step
    next();

  } else {
    // The user is not authenticated, we stop here
    res.status(401);
    res.send("Error during authentication");
  }
}

function getItems(req, res, next) {
  // Here we focus on the actual response, we assume that the user is authenticated
  res.send({ items: [] });
}

app.get("/items", authenticationMiddleware, getItems);
app.post("/items", authenticationMiddleware, createItems); // Re-use the same middleware

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I see. this clarifies alot of things

Comment: 'Controllers' aren't first order components of node/express. They are project artifacts if defined as such. Note, next response.

Answer (score 9):

If you're referring to the node/express terminology, *middleware* are simply the **callbacks** used by the routing functions/methods (get, set, delete, use, etc). Callbacks can either send or not send responses back to the client. The **callbacks** are really the **'controllers'** if you'd like to call them that (eg: ASP.NET Core MVC) but that's up to you. Below is a quote from [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). Note the term 'middleware' and where there's no mention of a 'controller'.

> *Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware
> function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next
> middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next.*
>
> *Middleware functions can perform the following tasks:*
>
> - *Execute any code.*
> - *Make changes to the request and the response objects.*
> - *End the request-response cycle.*
> - *Call the next middleware function in    the    stack.*

['Express'](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) also defines different types of middleware which is useful:

> - *Application-level middleware*
> - *Router-level middleware*
> - *Error-handling middleware*
> - *Built-in middleware Third-party middleware*

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes) another nice look at it from Mozilla's pov that does mention a few **controller/callback** examples.

Beyond that, you can define what a 'controller' is within your team and the naming convention follows from there. Key is your [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) profile and how you separate your concerns.